# php array slice every 2th rule

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array on PHP what outputs this in a TXT file:

```
Printing Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08
20.2 \nPrinting Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08
102.0 \nPrinting Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08
55.1 \nPrinting Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08
-18.3 \n
```

What is the point, i only need the nummeric values at the beginning of each rule. So the 20.2, 102.0, 55.1, -18,3 etc... This is just a example, there can be more or less in the txt file.

Now what to do? I have tested with the array slice function but i really can't exclude the rule:

```
Printing Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08
```

This is my array slice code...

```
$arraygood = array_slice($arraybad, 1, 4);
```

And the foreach loop to create the text file:

```
$file = fopen("array.txt","w");
foreach ($arraygood as $meting => $waarde) {
echo fwrite($file,$waarde . '\n');
}
fclose($file);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So... my understanding is that you have an array of strings, and you want to split each string so you only return the numeric value at the start; e.g: `20.2` - and then just write that value to a file. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, my understanding is that you have an array of strings similar to the following:

```
$lines = array(
    "Printing Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08",
    "20.2 \nPrinting Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08",
    "102.0 \nPrinting Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08",
    "55.1 \nPrinting Grid -- 1 Values -- Undef = -9.99e+08",
    "-18.3 \n"
);
```

And you want to extract the numeric value from the start of every string that starts with a numeric value, and write that value to a file.

If so, the following could be one basic way you could achieve that:

```
// init an array for the extracted numbers
$numbers = array();

// loop over each line
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // numeric values are suffixed by newlines - explode the string on newline
    // set a -1 limit to exclude the last element, in your case this should 
    // mean that only one value is returned per exploded string
    $tokens = explode("\n", $line, -1);

    // skip empty arrays or ones with null - this should exclude 
    // your 'header' line(s) as they have no newline char \n
    if (0 !== count($tokens) && null !== $tokens[0]) {
        // add the numeric value to the new array
        $numbers[] = $tokens[0];
    }
}

// done... you can save your values to file with fwrite() or file_put_contents()
var_dump($numbers);
```

Should yield:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '20.2 ' (length=5) 
  1 => string '102.0 ' (length=6)
  2 => string '55.1 ' (length=5)
  3 => string '-18.3 ' (length=6)
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Online example: https://eval.in/138676

You can write this array to a file a little more succinctly by doing something like:

```
file_put_contents('array.txt', implode("\n", $numbers));
```

Comment: Note: to trim the numbers and return, say `20.2` instead of `20.2 ` you should probably do `$numbers[] = trim($tokens[0]);`

Another way of doing this would be something like:

`$numbers = array_filter(array_map(function($line) {
    $tokens = explode("\n", $line, -1);
    if (!empty($tokens)) {
        return trim($tokens[0]);
    }
}, $lines));`